# User impersonation for entity framework only

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, impersonation

For our project, we have added an active directory group and have added login as well as write permission for that particular group in our database.

So whoever belongs to that particular group can access the site. The problem appeared when the user of that group can access database from outside as well since they have write permission as well.

So to solve this we removed write permission from all the tables and views for that user group and have given execute permission to stored procedure, which worked pretty well.

But then the problem was with entity framework which tries to update directly through view, so to solve that we added sql server login with username and password and now we have two connection strings one with `Integrated Security=true` and another with username and password, so now whenever we call stored procedure we use connectionstring with windows authentication and when we use entity framework for insert and update we pass connection string with username and password.

This is all working fine, now user can access database through our site but cannot insert/update from outside.

**First question** is, is this approach correct or there is any other better approach possible?

**Second question**, I have thought of one solution which is better than storing password in config file that if we can have a worker process account/application pool identity login in database and whenever I will use entity framework I will just impersonate the user or something similar.

So basically whenever I will call stored procedure I will go through current windows login and when I will use entity framework I will go through different user. But I am not sure how exactly I can achieve this.

(**We have a limitation that we cannot use worker process for stored procedure because we are calling functions like `SYSTEM_USER` etc. inside stored procedures so we have to call stored procedure with the actual user only**)

Comment: Although Windows has impersonation (one thread in a process temporarily adopting a security token that is not the token of the process) APIs need explicit support for it, and most don't. In particular, ADO.NET does not support impersonation. You really do need either a separate process, or (the more common approach) have your application manage authorization itself based on application roles rather than relying on your database to reject particular operations. Your application can then have full access with integrated authentication, and everyone else has no access.

Comment: I've told developers that I work with this before: just because you're using EF doesn't preclude your use of stored procedures. During the development cycle, do it the "normal" way and have EF generate the queries itself. Once you're satisfied it's doing what you want it to, slap a profiler on your database and see what EF is doing, wrap it in a stored procedure, and have EF call that instead. Note, you can skip a lot of that by just writing the procedure yourself.